# Is it possible to explicitly define the SDK against which deprecation warnings are given in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, warnings

I have a whole bunch of sourcecode which is used in a project which has a number of different app targets. Some of the targets have a Deployment Target of iOS 5.0, and some of them have a Deployment Target of iOS 6.0. When building the 6.0 target, I get a large number of deprecation warnings for methods that have been deprecated as of 6.0. Most of these methods have a replacement that was introduced in iOS 6.0, so I can't use the replacements for code that targets 5.0. While I can turn off all deprecation warnings using these two build settings:

GCC_WARN_ABOUT_DEPRECATED_FUNCTIONS = NO
CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS = NO

I would prefer not to turn them off entirely. Instead, I'd like to be able to explicitly tell the compiler to check for anything deprecated as of iOS 5.0. Is this possible? Does anyone have a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can silence specific warnings for a block of code using `#pragma clang diagnostic`. For instance:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

// Stuff that uses deprecated methods

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't know about methods. It just knows that the header says it's deprecated. You can make wrappers around the methods and do the right thing on each SDK (or just surpress the warning in one place). Or you can try building a static library for the shared code and build it against the older SDK (which *should* work, but you probably want to test it carefully).

Comment: The shared static library thing is the only solution that I know of to solve this, but unfortunately this project has a quite complex static library dependency tangle already, and I'd rather not mess with things to solve this particular problem.